# How to get rid of quotes linting requirement in react typescript vercel

Tags: eslint, vercel, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy a react typescript app on vercel.

I don't want to escape strings that include quotes.

I think i've asked politely for these rules to be dismissed:

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": "off",
    "avoidEscape": 0,
    "allowTemplateLiterals": true
  }
}
```

I keep failing deployments on vercel with the following compile errors:

> 3:27  Error: Strings must use singlequote.  quotes 39:281  Error: HTML
> entity, `"` , must be escaped.  react/no-unescaped-entities

I have disabled next lint cache. I still can't find the setting I need to use to ask eslint to let go of the requirement to escape quotes.

Can anyone help with the rule to get through vercel deployment?

I went back through the pages, and deliberately replaced every double quote with a single one. Example:

```
import React from 'react'

const News = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to the News wondering how to find where vercel thinks i've misused quotes for linting!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default News;
```

When I first tried to deploy this to Vercel, my import statement used "react" instead of 'react'. I have rebuild in npn, and pushed to git, I cannot get rid of the error that says:

1:19  Error: Strings must use singlequote.  quotes

I have even set strict to false and added more rules to my eslintrc.

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": "off",
    "quotes": [0, "double"],
    "avoidEscape": 0,
    "allowTemplateLiterals": 0,
    "no-useless-escape": 0
    
  }
}
```

The errors are exactly the same as they were when i used double quotes. I have seen several posts that say the avoidEscape setting hould be 'true'. I tried this, but get an error forcing me to pick between 0,1 and 2, where zero means off. I tried setting this to warn and get loads of non-descriptive warnings.

Can anyone help with what to try next so that I can deploy on vercel?

Bard suggested I make a vercel.json file with:

```
{
    "allowSingleQuotes": true
  }
```

I tried this but still get the same error in the vercel deployment build.

I also tried moving the import statement back to using double quotes - "react"  and still get the single quote required error. It does not seem to know which quotes I'm using, since it throws the very same error when the only quotes used are single 'react'.

npx eslint --fix does not change anything.

UPDATE: I made a completely new repo - from scratch, I deleted my previous vercel deployment, and tried again from fresh with a repo that does not use a single instance of a single quote (despite all of these eslint settings being expressed). I still get failed vercel deployments with error messages that cite a slightly different version of the same error message, being:

> 39:281  Error: `'` can be escaped with `&apos;`, `&lsquo;`, `&#39;`,
> `&rsquo;`.  react/no-unescaped-entities

For example, line 39 of the file it complains about has:

```
<p className="mt-4 text-md text-gray-700">
              Cookies are small pieces of text sent to your web browser by a website you visit. A cookie file is stored in your web browser and allows the Service or a third-party to recognize you and make your next visit easier and the Service more useful to you. Cookies can be persistent or session cookies. Persistent cookies remain on your personal computer or mobile device when you go offline, while session cookies are deleted as soon as you close your web browser.

            </p>
```

There isn't a single quote anywhere near this line.

Bard thinks that Vercel has made a false positive. I can't find a way forward.

when I inspect the deployment logs in vercel, I get a different error message. There, it says:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
> at exports.useMemo (/vercel/path0/node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-experimental/cjs/react.production.min.js:30:413)

When I google this error, it suggests deleting the .next and node_modules and reinstalling. I have tried this. I still get the same error.

Can anyone suggest what to try next?

Comment: Wow, I am having the same error while deploying my nextjs app. Have you found the solution ye?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you had shared, you had used an apostrophe in the `<h1>` tag. This might cause an error with `eslint`.

Hence try to use the below code:

```
import React from 'react'

const News = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{`Welcome to the News wondering how to find where vercel thinks i've misused quotes for linting!`}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default News;
```

Comment: As i said in the post above, i went through and removed all of the single quotes. The point of this question, is to get help in removing the requirement for quotes.